# library package manager for Windows question closed as not constructive

Tags: discussion, specific-question, not-constructive

My question [library package manager for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945313/library-package-manager-for-windows) was closed as non constructive (probably as a result of the meta-discussion from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127617/how-much-research-should-be-done-before-asking) because it was voted to close exactly by the people from there).

I don't see how this question is not constructive. It is simply asking for a package manager for Windows with some certain properties. Being non-constructive would mean (as I would understand it) that no constructive answer can be given. I fail to see how that is. Even if the answer is "no, there is no such thing", it would be constructive.

I also don't see why this is a bad question (as said in the discussion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127617/how-much-research-should-be-done-before-asking)). It asks for some software with some properties. I have asked it on StackOverflow because those properties make it esp developer related.

Any answer to this question would be helpful to all other people with the same question.

Can somebody elaborate why this question or any answers is of negative value to SO?

Comment: Do you plan to post one of these for each of the questions that were justifiably closed as a result of your previous question? If so, you'll likely hit the question limit here as well.

Comment: @M.Babcock: I don't really see what you all want to achieve. That I leave SO? There is still no single answer explaining why I am contributing negative value to SO by my question or my general activity. It just seems that you don't really like the way I use SO.

Comment: Albert: Not a single one of us really cared about how you used SO until you came here on meta to 1) complain and 2) not bother listening to our thoughts.

Comment: Of course that is not the intention. I'm not personally familiar with your questions outside of the ones you publicly highlighted, so in general I can't say you aren't contributing (nor have I said so). When asking questions it is generally expected that you "do your homework" and you've been extremely vocal about how this basic requirement is not necessary. This, in fact, does hurt the community as a whole. Before considering your response, understand that I will **not** be drawn into one of the pointless debates you've associated yourself with.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As the existing answers illustrate, you have asked a "List Question". Those are *never* good. There isn't a single good answer to them. There are dozens. No one else who sees your question will have the same set of requirements, so it won't help.

Therefore, list questions are *Not constructive*

Stack Overflow is not a place to build lists of stuff. There are *hundreds* of other places you can go for that.

Comment: Ah, thanks for explanation. Whereby two of the three given answers are actually not answers to the question, so it seems there is only a single right answer anyway (at this point). But I see your point. And btw., I think there are quite a few people with exactly this set of requirements (mostly Open Source developers though, maybe SO is not so Open Source user friendly, esp. not the Windows ones).

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place to build or wittle down a list of tools. Whether for open source or closed source; windows or Linux; newbie or experienced. It's a place for... oh, nevermind...

Comment: @Albert: I spend all day answering questions about open source tools. It's quite friendly here. It's just that your platform of choice doesn't provide an `apt-get` equivalent, and that's a serious piece to try to replace.

Comment: @sarnold: Yea, of course it is. But does it make my question bad? Also, Win isn't even my platform of choice. All I was trying to do is to compile some Open Source project on Windows with MSVC which had many dependencies on other libraries and it was a pain to download/install them manually and to configure MSVC to setup the include path etc etc. What I asked for in my question was a tool to simplify this.

Comment: @Albert: It makes your question a "List Question", which we close as "Not Contructive". But, I repeat myself, don't I?

Comment: No, actually [you repeat me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127567/why-are-we-limited-to-six-questions-per-day/127569#127569). This question is part 3 in a series.

Comment: @TheEstablishment hehe... I was gonna try to come up with some snarky way to say that, but decided to avoid the mental effort :p

Answer (score 12):

Since you're pinning it's closure on those that disagreed with you're previous MSO question, I'll explain my reasoning for vote closing it.

This question brings no value to SO because it would have been more constructive to do the search yourself. Google will automatically update based on recently found matches where any answers to your question would need to be manually updated. Posting a question to any of the StackExchange sites is **not** and should **not** be considered an alternative to doing your own research. That is why the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) says *Do your homework*, though I'd extend that beyond the walls of StackExchange and into the greater internet because the StackExchange network is *not* a [*let me google that for you*](http://lmgtfy.com/) service.

Comment: My question is not simply about a package manager for Windows. Have you even read it?

Comment: Would it matter if I did? It was on its way to being closed. Besides, the answer is still the same.

Comment: May I ask: How often have you setup MSVC for a project with many dependencies to other external libraries and prepared redistributable builds? (Hint: that is what the question is about ...)

Comment: Btw., Googling for "library package manager for windows" doesn't help as all. As you would unterstand if you have read the question...

Comment: @M.Babcock: I'm a little worried that you voted to close without reading the question -- don't get me wrong, I would have also voted to close, but I'd like to think we at least give every question a fair shake first.

Comment: @sarnold - I never said I didn't read the question. Unfortunately I wasted my time doing so, but knowing that this particular user _refuses_ to do any research before asking questions I was probably a little biased.

Comment: @M.B: Ah! I'm glad I misinterpreted your _Would it matter if I did?_ response. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I quote (emphasis mine):

> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve **facts**, references, or **specific expertise**; this question will likely solicit **opinion, debate**, arguments, **polling**, or **extended discussion**. [See the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) for guidance on how to improve it.

Comment: And this is false for the given question.

Comment: Five users with 3,000 or more reputation disagree with you.

Comment: Can you elaborate how any answer will not involve facts or references or expertise? Can you elaborate how any answer could be debatable?

Comment: Can I?  Yes.  Will I?  No.  I am not here to reiterate over and over again why some of your questions are not good questions for SO.

Comment: You still haven't.

Comment: Technically, you're right; however, that's because [it was already done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127627/164207). Are you able to give a single reason why you would listen to an explanation from me when you clearly either can't or won't listen to [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127627/164207)?

Comment: It says there "overly broad and solicits". That is both not true. It is quite specific. Have you read and understood the question?

Comment: Yes, I have.  Why should I answer any more of your questions when you've made it quite clear that you'll ignore any answers that you don't like?