# I'm a "help vampire", yet all my recent questions have high points

Tags: support, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

Here's a screenshot of my posts:

[image]

As you can see, I recently received -4 rep... But I still have a ton of +rep days. Why did I get marked as help vampire?

I've gone through my questions, quite a few people have agreed that they shouldn't be downvoted ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556730/unable-to-make-a-private-void-name-in-c-sharp#comment16912868_12556730))

How do I get out of being a help vampire?

---

<sub>Before I posted this, I got a thing about "I'm sorry, your account is not allowed to post anymore. Read about it here (goo.gl link)" or something. I just tried to post right now and I can (don't know if a moderator removed the help vampire status or something), but I wasn't able to before.</sub>

Comment: Hey, -4 + (+)186 still puts you up 182.. not so shabby HV ;)

Comment: I don't understand. Receiving down votes does not mean that people consider you a "help vampire", just that they didn't think your post was of good quality.

Comment: How were you "marked as a help vampire"?

Comment: .. yaknow.. , go on & BE A HELP VAMPIRE IF YOU GOTTA PY DEM BELLS SONNY

Comment: @JeremyBanks - My guess - Probably  a user..

Comment: You do know we max at 6 questiona  day?

Comment: @Adel I've asked 0 today.

Comment: I'm totally intrigued by this hidden "help vampire" flag, I want to make a badge-request too. Maybe.. "ZeroDay Vampire" somthn

Comment: @Adel There is no hidden "help vampire" flag... (And even if there was, we don't add badges for negative behaviour.)

Comment: @AnnaLear - Ah! maaan, it has a nice ring tho ;) But yes I understand you! Thank you!

Comment: From the comments below, it looks like @chipperyman573 was hit by the automatic IP filter ("“Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account"). I have no idea why he called it a "help vampire" flag, which only served to obscure his question...

Answer (score 14):

Getting downvoted doesn't mean you're a "help vampire".

Everyone gets a downvote now and then. For that matter, not all "help vampires" necessarily get downvoted all the time.

A downvote is a sign that there might be something incorrect about your post or that someone just generally didn't find it useful. Here on meta, they also signal [simple disagreement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq/#vote-differences). Don't take them personally.

It looks like on balance you're doing quite well.

Comment: I agree Anna - he does look pretty good overall. Good points thanks!

Comment: The [only proof](http://stackoverflow.com/users/39677/blankman) he needs to convince himself that he's not a help vampire...

Answer (score 6):

> Before I posted this, I got a thing about "I'm sorry, your account is not allowed to post anymore. Read about it here (goo.gl link)" or something. I just tried to post right now and I can (don't know if a moderator removed the help vampire status or something), but I wasn't able to before.

OK, now we *finally* get to the central problem.

Let's make one thing perfectly clear: you were not deemed a "help vampire". You were *question banned*. One of these is a potentially derogatory term that is sometimes used to put down people who ask "too many" questions. The other is an objective (though hidden) set of criteria that Stack Overflow uses to prevent people from repeatedly asking crap questions and making the site worse.

Question bans, as stated, are handed out based on a set of criteria that involves a complex formula of downvotes, deleted questions, and possibly other things. Whatever the case, you are likely riding the cusp of being question banned. So if you get more deleted questions and/or downvotes, you could be banned again.

I'm guessing (considering that I can't see deleted questions) that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011829/how-do-i-get-the-browser-in-php) is probably the anchor around your neck, with -7 downvotes. And no, deleting it will only make it worse. You asked an *extremely* common question that some basic research would have answered for you.

Just be more careful when you ask questions, and do your research *first*.

Answer (score 1):

To be blunt, anyone who asks *any* question can be deemed that term. Apparently someone was jealous of you learning so much. Don't feel bad, it's a mutually beneficial arrangement...

Keep it up, your questions are pretty solid overall!

Comment: Thanks... But how do I undo this? I mean, I'd like to actually USE the site I've spent my time getting over 200 rep on...

Comment: Also, being a "help vampire" prevents you from asking questions, which is the only reason I care. ("Keep it up, your questions are pretty solid overall!")

Comment: Mmm, about asking Q's, that's not so. I think you should read up on that...  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127567/why-are-we-limited-to-six-questions-per-day

Comment: Before I posted this, I got a thing about "I'm sorry, your account is not allowed to post anymore. Read about it here (goo.gl link)" or something. I just tried to post right now and I can (don't know if a moderator removed the help vampire status or something), but I wasn't able to before.

Comment: I found the goo.gl link by going through my history, it's: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers/

Comment: @chipperyman573 Did you follow the link in that message? If not, [here it is again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers). Study the suggestions there and use them when asking future questions so that they attract upvotes instead of downvotes. You can also check out [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for some extra tips. The question block is fully automatic based on several criteria and moderators don't have access to set it or lift it.

Comment: Do you have any deleted questions? They count toward the calculation of a question ban.

Comment: Nope, Adel: http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/

Answer (score -3):

Hmmm, your question seems to have prompted a bit of a love fest. From a purely objective point of view, let me make the following observations...

**Are you a help vampire?** Yes. Well, maybe. A [a definition](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) seems to say that a help vampire's questions are "crappy", I don't know if that term could be extended to someone who has an extremely lopsided question/answer ratio.

**Why?** Because you ask way (waaaaaayyyyy) more questions than you provide answers. (19 questions to just one answer at the time of writing this).

To a certain degree it doesn't matter that you've received a few up votes for your questions, you've also received a few down votes. Most of your questions are of a higher quality than those of the normal help vampire. However Stack Overflow isn't a help or learning service, it is a Q&A site. There is a subtle distinction there - users are encouraged to give back in the form of answers. This was one reason why the value of an up vote for questions was decreased from 10 rep down to 5 rep - to stop people building high rep scores by asking questions alone, it was to emphasize the importance of answers.

**Should I stop asking questions?** No, absolutely not.

> How do I get out of being a help vampire?

"[Help vampire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire?sort=faq&pagesize=50)" is a perception, there is no absolute measure to say what it is. Do make sure that your question quality is good, and that you are not asking questions that could easily be solved with a simple bit of research on your behalf. But be aware that you may continue to be viewed (by some) as a help vampire until you turn your question/answer stats around.

*Note: I'm expecting that this answer will rub a few up the wrong way. There's nothing personal, it's an objective viewpoint based on looking at the OP's stats. I'm attempting to directly address the "help vampire" accusation rather than just offering bland encouragement and validation (to just do that turns this into a counseling session).*

Comment: All my questions are ones that are specific to my programs. I just started learning C# (my first language) about 3 months ago - not enough to help people (yet!), but enough to be making things complicated enough to ask for help.

Comment: @chipperyman573 That's fine, I don't begrudge you that, and my answer says you should continue to ask questions. I'm simply elaborating on why some may see you as a help vampire. Your question evoked a bunch of cluck-clucking and encouragement (which isn't bad) but that didn't offer a specific answer as to why you faced that accusation.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks. Always helpful to see it from both sides.

Comment: A help vampire is someone who doesn't learn from their mistakes, others answers, or generally learn anything at all. Someone who asks questions more often than they post answers isn't a help vampire, someone who asks for help for every little problem and does no work on their own and doesn't give back to the community at all is a help vampire. Correlation vs causation; help vampires have more questions than answers, but more questions than answers does not make a help vampire.

Comment: Uhhh... Does anyone have ANY clue why this question is white?

Comment: @chipperyman573 It's a style that's applied to answers that are not popular :)